# How to set "64-bit" Windows Media Player as the default media player?

Tags: windows, windows-8, 64-bit, windows-media-player

I'm using 64-bit version of Windows 8.1 Pro. It always run the **32-bit** version of **Windows Media Player**.

[image: 32-bit wmp process]

How can I set the 64-bit version as the default player or whenever I chose to open music files with WMP?
I manually set the location of 64-bit `wmplayer.exe` as default program of music file types. It doesn't work.

I have also tried modifying the registry setting of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wmplayer.exe`

Which is suggested [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/making-windows-media-player-64-bit-default/bd4872b3-75e8-4d81-ae8a-df50798d5113). But, still no luck, any ideas?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Sorry, overread the part where you mentioned the link.

Comment: They included the 64-bit player with their 64-bit OS. That's the reason I'm trying to use it. Not related to anything else. @miniBill

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for Windows 7 are [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-set-64-bit-windows-media-player-12-wmp12-as-default-player/). It's likely that these will be the same for Windows 8.1

Note that it's generally not recommended to switch to the 64-bit version. You will lose compatibility with 32-bit codecs and plug-ins. And there's no noticeable improvement when using the 64-bit version.